# Show class methods in objective c

Tags: xcode, methods, xcode4

In java if you write myInstance.(list of methods here) you get a list of all methods, but in objective c you write [myInstance (method)] and you have to write a character to see all methods who starts with this character.

It is possible to show all methods without writing the first character? like [myInstance (list of methods here)]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode does have intellisense.  Just hit the **ESC** key  after a space and it will display all the methods.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to write in this way

```
[myInstance *]
```

instead of `*`, you have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> key....